# Is it possible to validate multiple values upon form text entry in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

Here is my code:

```
function validate() {
    if (document.getElementById('check_value').value == 'this') {
        $('#block').fadeIn('slow');
    }
    else {
        alert("Nope. Try again");
    }
}
```

I try doing this:

```
function validate() {
    if (document.getElementById('check_value').value == 'this','that','those') {
        $('#block').fadeIn('slow');
    }
    else {
        alert("Nope. Try again");
    }
}
```

...and it just accepts absolutely anything that's entered. Is this even possible to do?

Comment: If your comment is relevant to the question you should edit your question and add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
var val = document.getElementById('check_value').value;

if (val  == 'this' || val =='that'  || val =='those'){
     //pass
}
```

If you want to accept  any thing just remove the if condition or check the `length` of the `value`

```
    if (val.length >0){
      //pass
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This works too.

```
function validate() {
    var acceptableValues = { 
        this: undefined, 
        that: undefined, 
        those: undefined 
    },
    value = document.getElementById('check_value').value;

    if ( acceptableValues.hasOwnProperty(value) ) {
        $('#block').fadeIn('slow');
    }
    else {
        alert("Nope. Try again");
    }
}
```

and this:

```
function validate() {
    var value = document.getElementById('check_value').value;

    switch (value) {
        case: 'this':
        case: 'that':
        case: 'those':
            $('#block').fadeIn('slow'); break;
        default:
            alert("Nope. Try again");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never seen anyone doing it like this, what are the benefits of this? Is it faster?

Comment: Yeah, a lookup on an object would be faster than iterating over an array or doing a string search, but the efficiency gain is non-existent at this scale;

Comment: I understand, but I like to teach myself to work with the most efficient ways possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array for the allowed values and use indexOf to check. Like this:

```
function validate() {
    if (['this','that','those'].indexOf(document.getElementById('check_value').value) == -1)  {
        $('#block').fadeIn('slow');
    }
    else {
        alert("Nope. Try again");
    }
}
```

Comment: No need. the array is of strings.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

You need to compare every single option with the `||` operator.

An other option would be to use regexp like that :

```
function validate() {
    var values = ['this', 'that', 'those'];
    if (document.getElementById('check_value').value.search(new RegExp('^('+values.join('|')+')$')) > -1) {
        $('#block').fadeIn('slow');
    }
    else {
        alert("Nope. Try again");
    }
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/78PQ8/1/

You can aswell create your own prototype this type of action:

```
String.prototype.is = function(){
    var arg = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return this.search(new RegExp('^('+arg.join('|')+')$')) > -1;
}
```

and call is like that:

```
function validate() {
    if (document.getElementById('check_value').value.is('this', 'that', 'those')) {
        $('#block').fadeIn('slow');
    }
    else {
        alert("Nope. Try again");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `regex test` like,

```
var myregex=/this|that|those/i;

function validate() {
    if(myregex.test(document.getElementById('check_value').value)){
        $('#block').fadeIn('slow');
    }
    else {
        alert("Nope. Try again");
    }
}
```

**Updated,** if you want to validate only for `this,that and those`
Then try this `regex`,

```
var myregex=/^(this|that|those)$/i;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var correctArr = ['this','that','those'];

function validate(val){
    isCorrect = false
    $.each(correctArr, function(index,element){

            if(val.indexOf(element)>-1){
                isCorrect =  true;
            }
        }
    )
    return isCorrect;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want every value to be possible:

```
var val = document.getElementById('check_value').value;

if( val.length > 0 ) {

}
```

Which means the string just has to be at least 1 character.. More common way is:

```
if( val != '' ) {

}
```